# Blazor SFgrid / Synfusion Toolbar element disappears with EnableAdaptiveUI

Tags: c#, blazor, syncfusion, syncfusion-blazor-sfgrid

I have an issue with a Syncfusion component in Blazor : SgGrid. I'm currently using Syncfusion v 19.3.0.54.

The problem is : when I enable EnableAdaptiveUI, my Toolbar dissapears. So I dont want to choose between responsive and my buttons...

The Tech choice is not mine but I have to deal with it.
I added the ** ** in the code to show you where de problem is.
The RowRendering line doesn't change a thing, but it doesn't work without EnableAdaptiveUI.

Also I'm a front Js/React dev, and, yhea its in c# so speak to me like if I was a 5 y/o.

Thanks

```
 <SfGrid ID="DataGrid" @ref="DataGrid"
                DataSource="@listeSyndics"
                ** Toolbar="@(new List<object>() { "ExcelExport", "PdfExport", new ItemModel() { Text = "Enlever les filtres", TooltipText = "Enlever les filtres", PrefixIcon = "e-remove_filters", Id = "RemoveFilters",  Align = (Syncfusion.Blazor.Navigations.ItemAlign.Right) }, "Search" })" **
                AllowExcelExport="true"
                AllowPdfExport="true"
                AllowFiltering="true"
                AllowPaging="true"
                AllowSorting="true"
                EnableHover="true"
                AllowSelection="false"
                RowRenderingMode="@(Width >= MinWidthSize ? RowDirection.Horizontal: RowDirection.Vertical)"
                **EnableAdaptiveUI="true"**
                >
```

Answer (score 0):

We have faced a similar issue in our previous versions and we have fixed the issue and it is included in our Essential Studio 2022 Volume 1 release v20.1.0.47. So please upgrade to our latest version to resolve the reported issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
Unfortunatly after upgrade to v20.1.0.47, my table columns are no longer in front of the names column. And icing on the cake the responsive does not work at all.